# Open a pdf document from selected value in combobox - Userform

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, combobox, userform

I am looking for a solution for my case.

I am in the middle of making macro for my department and I just get stuck.

I have 6 different career paths and I would like to link pdf documents to the value in combobox. This is what it's looks like. I have a combobox as the screenshot below:

[image: combobox]

The data for the combobox is in the other worksheets which are hidden:

[image: data]

What I want to do is, if the value in the combobox is for example "Assertiveness in practice" then after clicking the command button "Read" I would like to open the pdf file which is in `B1` column.

[image: chosen value]

[image: path]

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can open the file... the following is one example of how to do that (plus a subroutine to test the code).  Just change the code as mentioned below.

Modify your existing Button Click to add the 'OpenFile line as shown.
Pass the FULL path and filename.
I assume your comboBox has the path as a column in the comboBox? If
    not, you should add it as a hidden column

```
 Private Sub cmdRead_Click()
        ' whatever code you have or need
        OpenFile Me.cboXXXX.Column(1)     ' Change to the name of your combobox AND column # of Full Path
        ' whatever other code you want
    End Sub


'---- Create a new module and paste all of the following code in it

Option Explicit
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Function OpenFile(sFileName As String)
On Error GoTo Err_OpenFile

    OpenFile = ShellExecute(Application.hWndAccessApp, "Open", sFileName, "", "C:\", 1)

Exit_OpenFile:
    Exit Function

Err_OpenFile:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_OpenFile

End Function

Public Function TestOpeningFile()
On Error GoTo Err_TestOpeningFile

    OpenFile "C:\Windows\Win.ini"

Exit_TestOpeningFile:
    Exit Function

Err_TestOpeningFile:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_TestOpeningFile

End Function
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for the information. I don't see any line to the command button, so I should assign the above code to the command button? Or should I just insert to the userform?

Comment: I will update the answer in a minute with a 'generic call' that you will need to change the names of controls. That will do the trick...

Comment: Is there anyway I can upload my macro on the website? I think it will be much easier to see what's happening

Comment: Is it a 'Macro' or is it VBA code? IF VBA, then just copy and paste.  If a Macro, and small, you could screen print or you can convert it to VBA code, then copy/paste. To convert, right click the macro, select 'Design View'. Then look at the ribbon,on the left, and you should see 'Convert Macrso to Visual Basic' Click that, then copy/paste the code.

Comment: Glad it is working. Was the code helpful or did you take a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Sub Training()

Call Workbook_Open

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open() 'open the msgbox with the message and username.
MsgBox "            " & ("Welcome") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "        " & Application.UserName

Userform1.Show

End Sub



In Userform I got:


    Private Sub Analytical_Button_Click()

Analytical_userform.ComboBox1.Clear

For Each cell In Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analytical").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analytical").Range("A200"))
    If cell.Value <> "" Then Analytical_userform.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

Analytical_userform.Show


End Sub


Private Sub Client_Button_Click()

Client_userform.ComboBox1.Clear

For Each cell In Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Client").Range("A200"))
    If cell.Value <> "" Then Client_userform.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

Client_userform.Show


End Sub

Private Sub Expert_Button_Click()

Expert_userform.ComboBox1.Clear

For Each cell In Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Expert").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Expert").Range("A200"))
    If cell.Value <> "" Then Expert_userform.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

Expert_userform.Show

End Sub


Private Sub Managerial_Button_Click()

Managerial_userform.ComboBox1.Clear

For Each cell In Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Managerial").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Managerial").Range("A200"))
    If cell.Value <> "" Then Managerial_userform.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

Managerial_userform.Show

End Sub

Private Sub Project_Button_Click()

Project_Userform.ComboBox1.Clear

For Each cell In Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project").Range("A200"))
    If cell.Value <> "" Then Project_Userform.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

Project_Userform.Show

End Sub

Private Sub Trainer_Button_Click()

Trainer_userform.ComboBox1.Clear

For Each cell In Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trainer").Range("A1"), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trainer").Range("A200"))
    If cell.Value <> "" Then Trainer_userform.ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
Next cell

Trainer_userform.Show

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Please check the snapshots:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e90VC.jpg)
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EWek.jpg)

I want to open a training by clicking the "Read" button